# USB Debugging is not working on MK809V Android stick

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-tv

I have enabled USB debugging on my MK809V stick:
[image]

Connected the relevant cables as such:
[image]

However, I do not see the MK809V stick under the list of remote devices in my Chrome browser...
[image]

Note that when I enable USB debugging on my Android phone (OnePlus 6) and connect it to the Mac, I DO see it in Chrome...

I have tried several cables (thought maybe the cable might be faulty), but unable to get it to work.
Also tried it in another computer and it is not working there either.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the problem WAS with the cable.
After playing around with various cables, I found out that works I can finally debug the app.

Comment: I can't believe I tried 3 different laptops and reinstalled 3 different OS in order to try and discover this dongle's USB... before trying your solution and picking the right cable :-(
Thanks though.